# Graph API, getting Team/Channel members from private channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I need to get the list of members from a SPA that is hosted as a tab in a private channel in Microsoft Teams. I know how to query it from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels-life-cycle-management#list-and-update-roles-of-owners-and-members-in-a-private-channel). So the request is something like this:
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<group_id>/channels/<channel_id>/members`
The problem is from the SPA I couldn't get the groupId because in a private channel the [context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context) provided by Microsoft Teams SDK is undefined. I know that this is done to provide privacy for the channel. But, are there any other queries that I could use to get the members, or is there any other way to get groupId from a private channel?

Comment: Hi @ingmar ramzan shidqi, To get the list of members from a private channel, you can call GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedteams  and get the corresponding Team ID/Group ID and call GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Teams/{groupID}/channels/{PrivateChannelID}/members

Comment: is the issue resolved?

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test it yet. Most likely today I will.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work since private channels are not included in graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedteams query result

Comment: Get Teams ID from graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedteams and call graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Teams/{TeamsID}/Channels then you would get all the channels including private channels.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now. It's just it may take many queries depending on the number of joined teams to get it right?

Comment: Yes, this requires a work around  with APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying Answer from the comments

To get the list of members from a private channel, you can call GET graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedteams and get the corresponding Team ID/Group ID and call GET graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Teams{groupID}/channels/{PrivateChannelID}/members

Comment: The API you are referring to is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-members