# List private team channel members with Microsoft Graph API in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

My application for Microsoft Teams works as a [tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs) and needs to get the list of the [chat members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or [channel members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), depending on where it is installed.

`/chats/{chat-id}/members`

`/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/members`

To use the APIs, I get the [Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context) object from the [client SDK library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/teams-js) to get the identifiers required for the APIs. It works fine for chats–both group and one on one (using `Context.chatId`), and *public* team channels (using `Context.groupId` and `Context.channelId`).

However, nothing I try seems to work for *private* team channels.

The context object returned for private team channels contains `teamId` and `channelId`, but **they are equal**, and using one value for both ids naturally doesn't work. Here is an example of what is returned for a private team channel by the SDK library 1.11.0 (the latest):

```
{
  "locale": "en-us",
  "theme": "default",
  "subEntityId": "",
  "isFullScreen": false,
  "sessionId": "5194fd2b-5c9a-16a7-7411-94ddabffffff",
  "chatId": "",
  "meetingId": "",
  "parentMessageId": "",
  "hostClientType": "desktop",
  "tenantSKU": "unknown",
  "jsonTabUrl": "microsoft-teams-json-tab.azurewebsites.net",
  "userLicenseType": "Unknown",
  "appSessionId": "7503c11c-d524-409c-b58b-004810ffffff",
  "appLaunchId": "c736c663-cc0b-47c3-8824-ba56b7ffffff",
  "isMultiWindow": false,
  "appIconPosition": 79,
  "userClickTime": 1637007245298,
  "sourceOrigin": null,
  "userFileOpenPreference": "inline",
  "osLocaleInfo": {
    "platform": "macos",
    "regionalFormat": "en-gb",
    "longDate": "d MMMM y",
    "shortDate": "dd/MM/y",
    "longTime": "HH:mm:ss z",
    "shortTime": "HH:mm"
  },
  "frameContext": "settings",
  "isTeamArchived": false,
  "teamType": 0,
  "userTeamRole": 0,
  "channelRelativeUrl": "/sites/ffffff/Shared Documents/Devel",
  "channelId": "19:0bc109b412d9448bb6b1b3d4d485700b@thread.tacv2",
  "channelName": "Devel",
  "channelType": "Private",
  "defaultOneNoteSectionId": "",
  "teamId": "19:0bc109b412d9448bb6b1b3d4d485700b@thread.tacv2",
  "teamName": "Devel",
  "teamSiteUrl": "https://ffffff.sharepoint.com/sites/worldrtech-Devel",
  "teamSiteDomain": "ffffff.sharepoint.com",
  "teamSitePath": "/sites/ffffff",
  "teamTemplateId": "",
  "teamSiteId": "",
  "ringId": "general",
  "tid": "d158bb9f-f90c-422d-9d0d-0040efffffff",
  "loginHint": "ffffff@ffffff.uk",
  "upn": "nox@worldr.co.uk",
  "userPrincipalName": "ffffff@ffffff.uk",
  "userObjectId": "fc5a4a6d-60e2-4370-83bd-aab1baffffff"
}
```

You can see above that the two are equal:

```
"channelId": "19:0bc109b412d9448bb6b1b3d4d485700b@thread.tacv2"
"teamId": "19:0bc109b412d9448bb6b1b3d4d485700b@thread.tacv2"
```

<s>I wonder, whether this is an expected behaviour, or something is broken there...</s>  As per comment by @Prasad-MSFT, this is normal behaviour for private channels.

There is an answer suggesting that one should first list all the [teams the user joined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469198/graph-api-getting-team-channel-members-from-private-channel). However, I don't see how I would connect this information to the context data shown above.

Is there a way to list the members of a private team channel? What am I missing?

**UPDATE1 16.11**:

I did an experiment, but the results got me puzzled. I followed the idea of getting all the teams of the user first. This got me ids of all the teams the user is a member of. I then requested members of for the current private channel for every team: *I expected to get errors* for all teams but one–that team the channel really belongs to. However, I got members for every request! That's very confusing.

1. `/me/joinedTeams`
2. `/teams/{id}/channels/{channel_id}/members` for each team received in 1. and `channelId` received from context.
3. **Each call returned some members**, which I did not expect...

**UPDATE2 16.11:**

This long-winded way gets me channel members in the end:

1. `/me/joinedTeams`
2. `/teams/{id}/channels` for each team received in 1.
3. Find the channel with `id` matching the `channelId` from my context among those received in 2.
4. `/teams/{id}/channels/{channel_id}/members` for the channel found in 3.

Looks like a lot of effort for such a simple thing.

Comment: Private channels are currently in private developer preview. When your content page is loaded in a private channel, the data you receive from the getContext call is obfuscated to protect the privacy of the channel. The following fields are changed when your content page is in a private channel: groupId: Undefined for private channels, teamId: Set to the threadId of the private channel

Comment: Thanks Prasad! But what can I do about listing the members of such a channel as a logged-in user who is a member of that channel? Surely, I can see the members when I'm a member. Can I get them from the API?

Comment: You can use this api(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/private-channels-life-cycle-management#list-and-update-roles-of-owners-and-members-in-a-private-channel) to get owner and member details of a private channel.

Comment: No, I can't. It includes `group_id`, and I don't seem to have an easy way to get it. See my latest update in the post.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other way to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A year later there seem to be some improvements! (Yeah, but not really, see below.)

There is a new property called `hostTeamGroupId` which appears to contain the correct team id for private channels. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context?tabs=teamsjs-v2#get-context-in-shared-channels), however, doesn't mention private channels specifically and only tells us about shared channels. Nevertheless, it seems to be working for the purposes of this question.

In `@microsoft/teams-js` v2 we can use `Context.channel.ownerGroupId`.

> hostTeamGroupId
>
> The property is newly added and describes the host
> team’s Azure AD group ID, useful for making Microsoft Graph API calls
> to retrieve shared channel membership.

### However

**This still doesn't work on mobile platforms at the time of writing 08.11.2022. The fields mentioned above are not populated.**

So, for mobile platforms, we still need my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Update: see the new answer from Nov 1 2022.

### Update 2: it's still not fully functional, use both. ‍♂️

This long-winded way gets me channel members list in the end. Only applies to private team channels because we don't have group id/team id in the Context there. As per @Prasad-MSFT's comment to the original post, there is no other way at the time of writing.

1. Get `/me/joinedTeams`
2. Get `/teams/{id}/channels` for each team received in #1.
3. Find the channel with id matching the `channelId` from the `Context` among those received in #2.
4. Get `/teams/{id}/channels/{channel_id}/members` for the channel found in #3.

Here is a caveat: if you create a private team channel and immediately add your tab to it, there is a chance that your new channel will not be returned by the API. If #3 in the above list of procedures fails, I ask the user to retry in a couple of minutes.